# How can I set this JFrame to be at the top of my screen?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, location, jframe

I've been trying to set a JFrame to the top of the screen for a long time. I've used setLocation(), setBounds() and a few other methods to no avail. All I want is a rectangle that blocks the top bar of the screen (where the minimize and exit buttons are). Here's my code, I'd appreciate any help!

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Annoy2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private boolean t = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Annoy2 inst = new Annoy2();
                inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                inst.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public Annoy2() {
        super();
        getDimensions();
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            GridBagLayout thisLayout = new GridBagLayout();
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            {
            }
            setUndecorated(t);
            setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            this.setResizable(false);
            pack();
            setSize(width, height);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getDimensions() {
        width = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Width: ", Math.round(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth())));
        height = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Height: ", 30));
    }

}
```

Comment: `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` centers the window on the screen. Why do you use it if you want the window to be on top of the desktop?

Comment: *"All I want is a rectangle that blocks the top bar of the screen (where the minimize and exit buttons are)"*  Use an undecorated `JFrame` or a `JWindow` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`, that causes your window to be centered on screen.

To place your window at the top of the screen, use `setBounds()` (in `initGUI()`:

```
setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
```

And you don't have to subclass `JFrame` to achieve this.

```
JFrame block = new JFrame();
block.setUndecorated(true);
block.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
block.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem. I had not realized that I had     inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);     in there.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been trying to set a JFrame to the top of the screen for a long
>   time

use `setAlwaysOnTop(true)`: Sets whether this window should always be above other windows. If there are multiple always-on-top windows, their relative order is *unspecified and platform dependent*. That is, If some other window is already *always-on-top* then the `relative order` between these windows is *unspecified (depends on platform)*. No window can be brought to be over the always-on-top window except maybe another always-on-top window.

> All I want is a rectangle that blocks the top bar of the screen (where
>   the minimize and exit buttons are).

use `setUndecorated(true)`: This method can only be called while the frame is not displayable. That is you will need to call this function on `JFrame` before you invoke `setVisible(true)` on it